# How to run geth for ropsten and mainnet in a same server?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, nodes

Is it possible to run geth for ropsten and mainnet in a same server if I changed all the port for Ropsten node trying not to conflict the ports used in mainnet? 
For example, `geth --rpcport 8546 --port 30301 --testnet` (for Ropsten) and geth (for mainnet)? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You must use different `port` and `rpcport` if you want to do this, just as you suggested.

```
geth --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 ...
geth --testnet --port 30304 --rpc --rpcport 8546....
```

*Note: the `port` and `rpcport` in the first command are not necessary, as they are the default values. I have included them in order to be explicit.*